# Isotope not responding to class name

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-isotope

I have a class that works with isotope.
The trigger class is loaded through jquery from a PHP file and is therefore not loaded right away.

I can see the class in the DOM, but not in the source code.

Should this stop it from working all together?

I am not sure what code I can post in relation to this, because it is a huge project and the content of the php loads fine through the jquery call, but the isotope does not work when I do it this way.

To clarify if I load it in the html file directly, the isotope works. So that is confirmed.
It only stops working when it loaded from the PHP file, however it is still displaying all the divs.

Any ideas?

========

## added binding code

```
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary active" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-filter=".chair">Chair</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-filter=".secretary">Secretary</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-filter=".treasurer">Treasurer</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-filter=".admin">Admin</a></li>
```

Thanks :-)

Comment: Could you please supply the relevant code

Comment: I wrote that there is no relevant code - the code is not what needs fixing. It is a matter of needing to get the isotope to work with code loaded into the DOM that is not there when the page first loads

Comment: Apologies, I meant how you're binding the isotope

Comment: Ah I see sorry :-) I am using data-filter - Added some code :-)

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't feel the specific code for calling/loading isotope is not relevant when you state that isotope does not work! data-filter is related to how isotope  filters items but not necessarily for it to load and  "work". What exactly does "the isotope does not work" mean?

Comment: I was more thinking that everything seems to work how it was just where I placed had an effect on it working on or not. But I got it working since I had to reload the isotope after it loaded the DOM.

Comment: Seems it was the code that needed fixing after all.

Answer (score 0):

It works now

I had to change

```
$('#menu-items').html(msg);
```

into this:

```
$('#menu-items').html(msg);
$('#menu-items').isotope('reloadItems');
```